# Web page to record audio and embed as data src?

Tags: node.js, html5-audio

I would like to be able to record an audio clip from my microphone and embed it in a StackExchange answer as per [this suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333512).

[This article](https://medium.com/jeremy-gottfrieds-tech-blog/javascript-tutorial-record-audio-and-encode-it-to-mp3-2eedcd466e78) has instruction on how to build such a page. I've copied the code from the article into JSFiddle but the code doesn't work because it requires the ffmpeg node library.

How can I make it work? And, for my education, why doesn't JSFiddle include node? It has lots of other frameworks (Angular and such). Why not node? Other REPL websites that do run node, don't have a window for HTML/CSS...

Also, if you happen to know a website that lets you record audio and copy HTML with a data src attribute, please let me know.

Comment: Pretty simple: Node doesn't run in the browser and Stack Snippets have no backend like repl.it and glitch and so forth do. Snippets don't support Angular since there's no unpkg/cdn version of Angular as far as I know (AngularJS, yes, but that's a different library). Stack Snippets is about as capable as jsfiddle or codepen, which (to my knowledge) don't have a backend. Anyway, since this question is about the capabilities of a Stack Overflow feature, it should probably go on meta (although it's likely a dupe there).

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for educating me. Still, my question is how can I make this work? It's not Stack specific. You may want to embed the <audio> in your blog.

Comment: Doesn't [the link you shared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333512) show how to do it? Record the audio, convert to base64 and drop it in an `<audio>` tag as shown. The other link seems totally unrelated--that shows how to let the visitor to the webpage record audio and send it to the server. Why would you want to add that to a SO answer?

Comment: @ggorlen It does, actually. Sorry, somehow I made myself believe the code needed ffmpeg and Node which it doesn't. Thanks for your comments.